# Can I put 'the' multiple times if it is important like in the below sentence?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

The sentence where I think 'the' can be put before:

The parliament of 'the' country is very important for 'the' people of that country.

Can I put 'the' before 'country' and 'people' in the above sentence beacuse I have to tell a particular thing or a single 'the' will be sufficient and correct?

Comment: Yes, all the instances of _the_ are required in that sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting Can you tell any sentence where we can use 'the' only a single time which can be sufficient?

Comment: Where there is a list of things that have already been mentioned. For example, in a recipe - _Sieve the flour, salt and baking powder together._ (We know how much of each from the list of ingredients.)

Comment: @KateBunting


If in the above question, for example, 'the' people of the 'country' have already been talked about and mentioned, then, can I omit 'the' before people and rewrite the sentence like below ?

'The' parliament is very important for people of that country

Comment: Well, _people_ is rather a special case because it can mean either 'human beings' or 'the members of a particular nation'. So _the people of [that country]_ means 'the nation as a whole', but _people of [that country]_ could refer to some/most of the individuals who live there.

Comment: That means putting a single time 'the' will be good if there is a list as you said before

Comment: @KateBunting If there is a college named xyz and if I write two sentences for example:  1: I have received a letter by the principal of 'the' college and if I have to write 2: I have received a letter by the principal of college. Is the second example correct as I have omitted 'the' before college but I have put 'the' before 'principal' that states that I am referring to a particular college (xyz) ?

Comment: _I have received a letter from the principal of XYZ College_ or, if the name has been mentioned before. _I have received a letter from the principal of the college._

Comment: If the name of the college has been mentioned before, then, from the subsequent/ next time, will it be important to 'the' before college each time whenever college word will be used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. In fact, if you use an article with *parliament*, you must use an article with the other words (as you have done).

However, from a U.S. perspective, since we don't have a parliament, I probably wouldn't use an article with *parliament* and I would would use **to** instead of **for** with *people*:

> Parliament is very important to the people of a country.

Comment: If there is a college named xyz and if I write two sentences for example: 1: I have received a letter by the principal of 'the' college and if I have to write 2: I have received a letter by the principal of college. Is the second example correct as I have omitted 'the' before college but I have put 'the' before 'principal' that states that I am referring to a particular college (xyz)

Comment: First of all, you receive a letter **from** the **president** or **dean** of the college. Second, yes you need to use an article with both because it's a specific president or dean and a specific college. If you say "College is a great learning experience" you don't need an article because it applies to any college.

Comment: @swmcdonnell oky, that means only one 'the' at the starting will not suffice for each common noun, we would have to use every time before it. Right ???